# How to list containers that are using redis/ubuntu image in Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to figure out the solution for the above question. I tried the  commands `docker ps -a -f "label=redis"` and `docker ps -f "name=redis"`, but that didn't gave any output.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the `ancestor` filter :

From the [Docker Docs on `ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/):

> `ancestor` - Filters containers which share a given image as an ancestor. Expressed as `image-name[:<tag>]`, `image id`, or `image@digest`

```
$docker run -d --rm redis 
c4cf36467d63c66f7d3d8271dd0f8e51ede4a627048eb5e294a2445f5b0d30ef
$ docker ps -f "ancestor=redis"
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c4cf36467d63        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 seconds ago      Up 15 seconds       6379/tcp            elated_yonath
```